# AttributeError after reinstall

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have been experimenting with several tracking algorithms on my Raspberry Pi 2- one of them being [CMT](https://github.com/gnebehay/CMT), which is implemented in Python. I got it working once, and then I ended up reinstalling Raspbian. After installing, CMT does not work, and I do not know why. Here is the output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 160, in <module>
    CMT.initialise(im_gray0, tl, br)
  File "/home/pi/CMT/CMT.py", line 29, in initialise
    self.detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create(self.DETECTOR)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FeatureDetector_create'
```

My assumption is this means that OpenCV wasn't installed correctly, but I made sure that all the features were included. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using OpenCV 2.4 solved the issue. I had been using OpenCV 3 beta before.